# Access exportspreadsheet ignoring order by clause

Tags: excel, ms-access

I'm exporting a query from access with the ImportExportSpreadsheet macro function, and it seems to be ignoring the "order by" clause in the query, and the data gets mixed up in the resulting excel file. The only issue I can think of that is causing the issue, is that the field the query is ordered by is not an actual data point in the results. I'm ordering by an ID field in the data, but I don't want that in the exported final product.

Do I need to include that field for the export to follow the order in the query?

Below is the code of the query

```
SELECT [CW Log Deposits].Date, [CW Log Deposits].[Pay To], [CW Log Deposits].[Check Date], [CW Log Deposits].[Rec'd From], [CW Log Deposits].Attn, [CW Log Deposits].[Street 1], [CW Log Deposits].[Street 2], [CW Log Deposits].City, [CW Log Deposits].State, [CW Log Deposits].Zip, [CW Log Deposits].[City, State, Zip], Replace([Check Num],"CK#","") AS [Check No], [CW Log Deposits].Amount, [CW Log Deposits].Memo
FROM [CW Log Deposits]
ORDER BY [CW Log Deposits].[CW Log Num];
```

Comment: Normally you can use ORDER BY on a field that's not included in the SELECT. Can we see the query or maybe if you're adjusting your sheet afterwards, the full code?

Comment: I tested this with the External Data dialog and VBA. Data is not 'mixed up'. I don't use macros.

Comment: But then I tested with macro and still no issue. Something else is happening.

Comment: added code to original post. it is pulling from a Dataverse linked table, but i wouldn't think that would affect anything?

Comment: as a workaround, i changed the query to append to a table, and then exported the data in the table, which works.